# Fine-tuned MobileNet model returns the same output whatever the input is [Image classification - Emotion Recognition]

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, image-classification, fine-tuning

I fine-tuned an image classification model based on the MobileNet model from tensor hub. My goal is to predict the emotion on a face wearing a VR headset between positive, negative and neutral.

I built my dataset over the FER2013 dataset, by putting both "fearful", "sad", etc. on negative and "happy" on positive, "neutral" on "neutral". I then applied a mask to my images to simulate the presence of a headset on the faces. I froze the 15 first layers of the model (70 layers in total) and tried to fine-tune the MobileNetmodel over my dataset.

**The problem is that my model is always returning the same label whatever the input is.
**

Here is how the code looks like for building the model :

```
# Create model using MobileNet as the base model
mobile_net_bal = MobileNet(
    input_shape=(128, 128, 3),
    include_top=False, #because we will add our own top layer !
    weights="imagenet",
    classes=3
)

# Get the output from the 14th layer of MobileNet
mobile_net_output = mobile_net_bal.layers[-14].output

# Apply global max pooling to reduce the spatial dimensions
global_pool = GlobalMaxPool2D(name="global_pool")(mobile_net_output)

# Add a fully connected layer with softmax activation for classification
out = Dense(3, activation="softmax", name="out_layer")(global_pool)              #the change occurs here

# Create the final model with MobileNet as the base and the new classification layers
model = Model(inputs=mobile_net_bal.input, outputs=out)

# Freeze the first 15 layers to prevent their weights from being updated during training
for layer in model.layers[:15]:
    layer.trainable = False

# Compile the model with categorical cross-entropy loss, Adam optimizer, and accuracy metric
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=Adam(0.01), metrics=["accuracy"]) #sparce because else it works on one-hot encoded target

# Define callbacks for model training
filepath = "models_balanced_cuts"

# Save the best model based on validation accuracy during training
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath,
    monitor="val_accuracy",
    verbose=1,
    save_best_only=True,
    mode="max"
)

# Stop training early if validation accuracy does not improve for a certain number of epochs
earlystopping = EarlyStopping(
    monitor="val_accuracy",
    patience=15,
    verbose=1,
    mode="auto",
    restore_best_weights=True
)

# Reduce learning rate when validation accuracy plateaus
rlrop = ReduceLROnPlateau(
    monitor="val_accuracy",
    mode="max",
    patience=5,
    factor=0.5,
    min_lr=1e-6,
    verbose=1
)

# Store all the callbacks in a list
callbacks = [checkpoint, earlystopping, rlrop]
```

For training :

```
# Train the model using the provided training and validation data. Store the training history
history_base = model.fit(
    X_train_processed,
    Y_train,
    validation_data=(X_val_processed, Y_val),
    validation_steps=X_val_processed.shape[0],
    epochs=25,
    steps_per_epoch=X_train_processed.shape[0],
    callbacks=callbacks
)
```

Here is the output :

```
Epoch 1/25
13015/13015 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.1916 - accuracy: 0.3386
Epoch 1: val_accuracy improved from -inf to 0.34313, saving model to models_balanced_cuts
WARNING:absl:Found untraced functions such as _jit_compiled_convolution_op, _jit_compiled_convolution_op, _jit_compiled_convolution_op, _jit_compiled_convolution_op, _jit_compiled_convolution_op while saving (showing 5 of 24). These functions will not be directly callable after loading.
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: models_balanced_cuts\assets
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: models_balanced_cuts\assets
13015/13015 [==============================] - 509s 39ms/step - loss: 1.1916 - accuracy: 0.3386 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.3431 - lr: 0.0100
Epoch 2/25
13014/13015 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.1238 - accuracy: 0.3300
Epoch 2: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.34313
13015/13015 [==============================] - 493s 38ms/step - loss: 1.1238 - accuracy: 0.3300 - val_loss: 1.1224 - val_accuracy: 0.3263 - lr: 0.0100
Epoch 3/25
13015/13015 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.1226 - accuracy: 0.3367
Epoch 3: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.34313
13015/13015 [==============================] - 492s 38ms/step - loss: 1.1226 - accuracy: 0.3367 - val_loss: 1.1453 - val_accuracy: 0.3263 - lr: 0.0100
```

It goes like this for 16 epochs (120min training time). And here goes my confusion matrix :

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.00      0.00      0.00       922
           1       0.33      1.00      0.50       918
           2       0.00      0.00      0.00       950

    accuracy                           0.33      2790
   macro avg       0.11      0.33      0.17      2790
weighted avg       0.11      0.33      0.16      2790
```

Finally, my dataset is made of 6198 positive images, 6198 neutral images and 6198 negative images. Here is the output of `np.unique(Y_bal, return_counts = True` : `(array([0, 1, 2]), array([6198, 6198, 6198], dtype=int64))`

My datasets were produced the following way. I reshaped my images from 48px greyscale to 128px RGB (3 times same channel) to match the images' format the MobileNet model was trained on. I know it's really bad to do so, but I don't know what other thing to try.

```
X = np.array(X_bal)
Y = np.array(Y_bal).reshape((len(Y_bal), 1)) #else just array of big list
n = X.shape[0]

# Split the data and labels into training and temporary sets (85% for training, 15% for temporary)
X_train_temp, X_test, Y_train_temp, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.15, random_state=42, stratify=Y)

# Split the temporary sets into training and validation sets (60% for training, 20% for validation)
X_train, X_val, Y_train, Y_val = train_test_split(X_train_temp, Y_train_temp, test_size=0.15/0.85, random_state=42, stratify=Y_temp)

# Print the shapes of the resulting sets
print("Training set shapes:", X_train.shape, Y_train.shape)
print("Validation set shapes:", X_val.shape, Y_val.shape)
print("Testing set shapes:", X_test.shape, Y_test.shape)
print("Repartition between sets : ", X_train.shape[0]/n, X_val.shape[0] / n, X_test.shape[0] / n)

#48px -> 128px / intermediary process
X_train_processed = fun.upscaler(X_train, (128, 128))
X_val_processed = fun.upscaler(X_val, (128, 128))
X_test_processed =  fun.upscaler(X_test, (128, 128))

#1 channel -> 3 channels
X_train_processed = np.stack(list(map(fun.grey_to_colour, X_train_processed)))
X_val_processed = np.stack(list(map(fun.grey_to_colour, X_val_processed)))
X_test_processed = np.stack(list(map(fun.grey_to_colour, X_test_processed)))
```

Output :

```
Training set shapes: (13015, 48, 48) (13015, 1)
Validation set shapes: (2789, 48, 48) (2789, 1)
Testing set shapes: (2790, 48, 48) (2790, 1)
Repartition between sets :  0.6999569753683984 0.14999462192104981 0.15004840271055178
```

[Extract from functions.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CssPJ.png)

Also, my dataset is made of masked images, so the problem might as well come from the fact the model is not able to learn from such images. Here is how they look (`labels = ['negative', 'neutral', 'happy']`):

[dataset sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiEFW.png)

Thank you very much for your interest in my problem. Tell me if you need access to any other piece of information !

NB : It's my first question, and I'm a total newbie on asking questions AND in deep learning / fine-tuning so I may be writting ludicrous things. The configuration for the neural network mainly comes from this webpage : https://www.edlitera.com/en/blog/posts/transfer-learning-emotion-detection.

**Please don't hesitate to correct me and to share your insights about my case, even if it is not by correcting my code, but any alternative way of dealing with my task would be very welcome. Thank you !**

NB 2 : I feel like there are no relatable cases on stack overflow, but don't hesitate to tell me if there is one. Thank you again.

First, I had a very unbalanced dataset. So the model was just always returning the same just predicted label. But since there was one label taking 60% of the whole dataset, I told myself "OK that's one way to optimize accuracy".

But now that my dataset is perfectly balanced (as all things should be - Thanos), I really don't have a clue on what is going on. I'm just guessing that the model cannot learn from my dataset.

I have checked that my labels in Y corresponded to my images in X and it is the case...